# Unique Pointer Initialization

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm still new to c++, apologies if this is obvious, but I could not find a good answer after much googling.
I wish I could write the following code.

```
class Test {
public:
    Test();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Dummy> m_Dummy;
};
```

```
Test::Test() {
    auto data = // generate some data here
    m_Dummy = std::make_unique<Dummy>(data);
}
```

What happens:
The assignment operator on m_Dummy calls `unique_ptr::reset`,
which calls delete on the pointer,
which calls the m_Dummy destructor,
and running the destructor creates a segfault because it was never initialized.

The correct way would be to initialize it in the constructor initialization list.
But then I would not be able to pass in the data I want.

```
Test::Test() : m_Dummy{std::make_unique<Dummy>(data)} { // Don't have time to generate data
}
```

I am not sure how to make this cleaner.
My current idea is to change Dummy to have default constructor then an `initialize` function which takes the data.
It feels wrong though.

Is there a cleaner way to handle this?
What is normally done with smart pointers that need parameters and also need to be a class member?

Thanks,
Nathan

Edit:
From the answer below perhaps there is a completely different problem somewhere in my code causing this.
This is the callstack from the debugger just before the segfault is thrown.

```
Dummy::~Dummy Dummy.cpp:24
std::default_delete<Dummy>::operator() unique_ptr.h:78
std::unique_ptr<Dummy, std::default_delete<Dummy> >::reset unique_ptr.h:371
std::unique_ptr<Dummy, std::default_delete<Dummy> >::operator= unique_ptr.h:278
Test::Test Test.cpp:42
std::make_unique<Test, int&, double, double> unique_ptr.h:821
World::World World.cpp:25
Application::Run Application.cpp:77
main main.cpp:10
__libc_start_main 0x00007fbd47bbdb97
_start 0x0000555e1df657ea
```

Edit2:
The problem was that in the process of creating my data I was corrupting my memory and Dummy just happened to be the victim.
My original proposal to create the unique_ptr works now.

Thanks

Comment: The `unique_ptr` should be default-initialized to hold `nullptr`, making the `reset`/`delete` a no-op, not a segfault. Is there some reason you can't put the code to generate `data` in a function that returns `data`. so you can do the initialization as in your "Don't have time to generate data" example?

Comment: What does `~Dummy` look like?  Specifically line 24.

Comment: Its just an if statement a member variable is zero. But the variable is not there because the Dummy object is a null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens:
>   The assignment operator on `m_Dummy` calls `unique_ptr::reset`,
>   which calls `delete` on the pointer,
>   which calls the `m_Dummy` destructor,
>   and running the destructor creates a segfault because it was never initialized.

That is NOT what happens under *normal* conditions.

`m_Dummy` is not initialized *explicitly* in the `Test` constructor, so it gets *implicitly* default-constructed instead,  and its default constructor sets its held pointer to `nullptr`.

When a `unique_ptr` holds `nullptr`, `reset()` is a no-op.  It is perfectly safe to assign to a `unique_ptr` that is holding `nullptr`.

Even if `reset()` were not a no-op, it is perfectly safe to call `delete` on a `nullptr`.

That said, the ONLY way `Dummy`'s destructor could be getting called when assigning to `m_Dummy` is when `m_Dummy` is not holding a `nullptr`. For that to happen in the `Test` constructor you have shown, `m_Dummy` would have to be in an invalid state, either because:

- the `Test` constructor was called on invalid memory (unlikely, unless you are misusing `placement-new`)
- your code to initialize `data`, or even the `Dummy` constructor itself, is corrupting random memory, and `m_Dummy` is an unwitting victim of that corruption (more likely).

Comment: Thanks, maybe my data is getting corrupted, very possible.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `static` method to generate the data?

```cpp
class Test {
public:
    Test();

private:
    static Dummy makeConstructionData()
    {
      return Dummy();
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Dummy> m_Dummy;
};
```

Then later on you can do:

```
Test::Test() : m_Dummy{std::make_unique<Dummy>(makeConstructionData())} { 
}
```